# CSS text align on button with icon

Tags: css, button, leaflet

I have tested different suggestions from stack, but i still cant get it to work.

Im trying to center the text after the icon, but it keeps look like this: 
[button with icon and text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVR8Z.png)

My css is:

```
    .leaflet-bar button,
    .leaflet-bar button:hover {
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border: none;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      max-height: 1200px;
      max-width: 1200px;
      line-height: 50%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: middle;
       }

    .leaflet-bar button {
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 50%;
      vertical-align: middle;
      text-align: center;
       }
```

My idea from looking at this, was that the "text-align" should have done the work.

What do I miss?

EDIT: HTML SNIPPET:

```
   button: L.easyButton({
position: 'topright',
states: [{
  stateName: 'add-markers',
  icon: '<img alt="do this" src="icon-1.png" height="40" width="40" align="middle" style="opacity:0.4 "/><span id="text"><font color="black"><b>Hello World</b></font></span>',
  title: 'add random markers',
  onClick: function(control) {
    map.addLayer(markersWASH);
    control.state('remove-markers');
  }
}, {
  icon: '<img alt="do this" src="icon-1.png" height="40" width="40" align="middle"/>',
  stateName: 'remove-markers',
  onClick: function(control) {
    map.removeLayer(markers);
    control.state('add-markers');
  },
  title: 'remove markers'
}]
```

})

WHAT I WANT: 
[WHAT I WAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6kot.png)

Comment: Thanks, good point. But gives the same result. Does not make any changes :(

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Share your HTML please. We need a working demo that reproduces the screenshot.

Comment: Would you mind showing us what it should look like? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Why do you have the same styles applied to .leaflet-bar button and .leaflet-bar button:hover? Also so for your final product you want the text more aligned horizontally or vertically? Looks out of place in both directions tbh

Comment: I just made some edits. Hope it makes sense. 
On hoover the button change background color

Comment: I looked at this before: http://jsfiddle.net/paulftw/F3KyK/43/